# Read channel recent actions with telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

My bot is admin in a channel and I want to read channel's recent actions(like who joined the channel and etc) using python-telegram-bot. How can I achive this?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73270188/8583692) for how to read channel past messages using a user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have no method to get recently actions by bot. And bots won't get notified when users joined channel.

If you want to know whether user in your channel, there have `getChatMember` method.